# document.querySelectorAll( more than one dataset );

Tags: javascript, html, dataset, selectors-api

I am trying to use:

`document.querySelectorAll('[data-r=0 data-c=0]');`

to select a specific *HTML* element but it returns:

> *Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[data-r=0 data-c=0]' is not a valid selector.*

I'm trying to understand why. Is it not query by 2 datasets at once? All the examples I've found online only show examples of *querySelectorAll* with only one dataset in them. I'm trying to avoid using JQuery, is there any way?

```
    <table id="board">
        <tr>
            <td class="box" data-r=0 data-c=0></td>
            <td class="box" data-r=0 data-c=1></td>
            <td class="box" data-r=0 data-c=2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="box" data-r=1 data-c=0></td>
            <td class="box" data-r=1 data-c=1></td>
            <td class="box" data-r=1 data-c=2></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="box" data-r=2 data-c=0></td>
            <td class="box" data-r=2 data-c=1></td>
            <td class="box" data-r=2 data-c=2></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to add quotes so that the selector can be valid.
Then depending on what you actually want to select, you have two different syntaxes:

- `[data-r="0"][data-c="0"]` will select elements that have `data-r=0` AND `data-c=0`
- `[data-r="0"],[data-c="0"]` will select elements that have `data-r=0` OR `data-c=0`

The first behaviour is pretty well described in the [standard documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#attribute-selectors). The second one is simply a [selector list](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#selector-list). Of course, you can combine those. For example, you could select the diagonal of your table by using `[data-r="0"][data-c="0"], [data-r="1"][data-c="1"], [data-r="2"][data-c="2"]`.

---

### Demo

```js
// Matches 1 element
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[data-r="0"][data-c="0"]'));

// Matches 5 elements
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[data-r="0"],[data-c="0"]'));

// Matches the 3 diagonal elements
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[data-r="0"][data-c="0"], [data-r="1"][data-c="1"], [data-r="2"][data-c="2"]'));
```

```html
<table id="board">
    <tr>
        <td class="box" data-r=0 data-c=0></td>
        <td class="box" data-r=0 data-c=1></td>
        <td class="box" data-r=0 data-c=2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="box" data-r=1 data-c=0></td>
        <td class="box" data-r=1 data-c=1></td>
        <td class="box" data-r=1 data-c=2></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="box" data-r=2 data-c=0></td>
        <td class="box" data-r=2 data-c=1></td>
        <td class="box" data-r=2 data-c=2></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`[data-r=0],[data-c=0]` should work.

Comment: Without adding quotes around the integers it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Put your data-r=0 in '' (quotes)

```
 <td class="box" data-r='0' data-c='0'></td>
```

and use

```
document.querySelectorAll("[data-r='0'][data-c='0']");
```

don't forget to put attribute value in '' in querySelector